# Combine multiple Response into one Response

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jersey-2.0, jaxb2

I have the below which downloads a file with the content c50c4a23307529b59797525c52b2c50c *file1.zip

Now I want to combine file1Response and file2Response & return as json. Any help on how to do it?

```
@GET
@Path("/" + getfileschecksum)   
@Produces("application/json") 
public Response getFilesChecksum() {
        String fileid1 = "file1";
        String fileid2 = "file2";


        Response file1Response = getChecksum(fileid1);
        Response file2Response = getChecksum(fileid2);

        return file1Response;


    }
```

tried adding an arraylist as follows:

```
@GET
    @Path("/" + getfileschecksum)   
    @Produces("application/json") 
    public Response getFilesChecksum() {
            String fileid1 = "file1";
            String fileid2 = "file2";

            ArrayList<Response> rp = new ArrayList<Response>();

            Response file1Response = getChecksum(fileid1);
            Response file2Response = getChecksum(fileid2);

            rp.add(file1Response);
            rp.add(file2Response);
            return Response.ok(rp).build();


        }
```

is returning the error com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

file1Response is coming from the below, can anything be changed below to return string.

```
            URL url = new URL(binpath);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            String mt = connection.getContentType();
            ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) is, mt);
            response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + binpath.substring(binpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, binpath.length()));
            return response.build();
```

Comment: I am assuming Response is the javax.ws.rs.core.Response object. First this won't work because it is an interface and you would have to add @JsonTypeInfo to it to tell the serializer how to serialize it. You need to convert your ArrayList to ArrayList<String> and put the actual string value in there rather than the Response object.

Comment: I tried file1Response.getEntity().toString(), but this returns weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream@458324f2 and not the actual content. How to get the String from Response?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
response.append(file1Response );
response.append(file2Response );

return response.toString();
```

No harm if it does not work,only trying to help.
But if it does thumbs up.

Comment: Didn't work & doesn't return the content from file1Response.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create another method that actually returns the string checksum and then have your resources method call that.

```
@GET
@Path("{file}/checksum")
Response getChecksum(@PathParam("file") final String file) {
    return Response.ok(calculateChecksum(file)).build();
}


@POST
@Path("checksums")
Response getChecksum(final List<String> toChecksum) {
    final List<String> checksums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : toChecksum) {
       checksums.add(calculateCheckSum(s));
    }
    return Response.ok(checksums).build();
}



private String calculateCheckSum(final String file) {
    // do your checksum
}
```

Comment: URL url = new URL(binpath);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            String mt = connection.getContentType();
            ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) is, mt);
            response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + binpath.substring(binpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, binpath.length()));
            return response.build();  this is what returns file1Response which needs to be fetched into a string.

Comment: I completely misread the question. You can't return a binary file as json, this is not possible. If you are trying to return two files binary files in a single request this also will not be possible as far as I can see. Even if you could the file would appear as one file and would be appear to be corrupted. If you need to download mutiple files you will need to archive them into a single zip,tar,rar etc on the server side before sending the single archived file. In your case it looks like it would be a zip of zips.

Comment: The file has text content only. Is it possible to read the content in java. or is there a way to use the ResponseBuilder to change the response to String from the file.

Comment: The file download will typically be base64 encoded text. So you can get text. I guess you could base64 encode the file and send it back as text. But a browser won't prompt you to download the file unless the Content-Disposition is set to attachment.

Comment: The encoding of the returned file is ANSI, I just need to get the contents & return it as a String or JSON, it doesn't need to be another file. Any help on how to do this?